# WPF UserControl: Use default WPF style rather than inheriting style of parent application

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I have a WPF User Control embedded in an application, which is inheriting the style of the application. I designed the User Control with the default WPF style in mind and it doesn't define its own resources/styles. However, as a result of inheriting the style of the host application, it doesn't look correct. I'd prefer if the User Control just used the default WPF style. Is there a simple way I can do this?

The UserControl itself consists of a `System.Windows.Controls.Frame`, which references a `System.Windows.Control.Page`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OrderParcelAddInPrototype.WpfControls.Controls.OrderParcelControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="450">
    <Frame Source="/OrderParcelAddInPrototype.WpfControls;component/Pages/MainPage.xaml" />
</UserControl>
```

Neither the `UserControl` or the `Page` define their own styles.

```
<Page x:Class="OrderParcelAddInPrototype.WpfControls.Pages.StartPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="450" Title="Main Page">

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="350" CanVerticallyScroll="True"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <!-- Removed for brevity -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Comment: please post your code/XAML ?

Comment: Have you tried `<UserControl Style="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}" />`?

Comment: I've just given that a go. It doesn't appear to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define your usercontrol style inside usercontrol resources and apply that style in user control

```
 <UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyUserControl"
         ...
         Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlStyle}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <Style x:Key="MyUserControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

otherwise, you can merge resource dictionary of your usercontrol by using
 mergeddictionary in resource dictionary in app.xaml